When opening folder via context menu VS code is being opened within that folder. But on other macbook Terminal is opened

When opening folder via context menu VS code is being opened within that folder. But on other macbook Terminal is opened.

If I remember correctly it is implemented with URL schemes. Maybe VSCode hijacked that.
